# Get a variable's values in a JAVA CLASS from a ACTIVITY

Tags: java, android, android-activity

I have a ACTIVITY which contains a editText (year), so I want to get the value of this editText in a JAVA CLASS, because in this java class I have a method that uses rawQuery, in this query I want to use the value of the variable (year from activity) in the clause WHERE, making a filter, so the app will just search datas with the year insert in the editText...

I tried like this:

In the JAVA CLASS I create a variable and its gettes and setters...
    private int year;

```
public NovoNivelGlicemicoDAO() {

}

public NovoNivelGlicemicoDAO(int ano) {
    super();
    this.ano = ano;
}

public int getYear() {
    return year;
}

public void setYear(int year) {
    this.year = year;
}

   // Method with query is here (obs: the method works fine, because if I use in the clause where, for example, 2013, it works, but when I try to get the year like this getYear() it does not bring any result.
```

My Activity is simple , I just call a constructor and use set:

```
JavaClass year= new JavaClass();

int year= (Integer.parseInt(ed_year.getText().toString()));

year.setYear(year);
```

Please, if someone knows why I can't get the year from the Activity, tell me ;)

Thank You.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You reinitialize `year` here

```
int year= (Integer.parseInt(ed_year.getText().toString()));
```

you need a new variable

```
JavaClass javaClass= new JavaClass();  //either rename this variable or the other one

int year= (Integer.parseInt(ed_year.getText().toString()));

javaClass.setYear(year);
```

If that is exactly how your code looks then I'm guessing it doesn't compile since `int` doesn't have a `setYear()` method. Also, I don't know how you are using it but you will lose that reference when the `Activity` is destroyed. If that is not what you want then you need to make a `static` variable in `JavaClass` to hold the value or store it in persistent storage.

**Update**

The problem is that the value in `JavaClass` is trying to be used from another `Activity`. Since the reference is created in this `Activity` it is lost when going to the next `Activity` where it is trying to be accessed. The variable `year` being created in `JavaClass` needs to be declared as `static` so it can retain its value even when leaving this `Activity`.

**Note** The functions that use it and the way it is accessed will need to be changed to `static` references.

Comment: The names are right, my project has portuguese variables names  (I'm Brazilian), so I changed the the names to put here.. I didn't understand when you said about the setYear() method. About the Activity, its only purpose is being a filter, so I call another intent with a listview using the method in the java class. (and if the getYear() worked the listview would just show the datas with the year of the editText.

Comment: I'm a little confused but I think what you want to do is make `year` in your Java class `static` so you don't lose the reference when you leave this `Activity`. You will then need to access it statically and make the methods `static`. I may be misunderstanding you still but you can try that.

Comment: You also could send the value to the next `Activity` as an `extra` in the `Intent` then set its value there

Comment: You're welcome. I will update my answer if you want to click the little checkmark and accept it